How to find the time comlexity when comparing sublists?


def check_lists(list_1, list_2):

    if list_1 == None:
        return None
    if list_2 == None:
        return None

    comparison_result = True

    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        if list_1[i] != list_2[i]:
            comparison_result = False
            break

    if comparison_result:
        return list_1
    else:
        return None

def check_sublists(lst, fir, la):
    mid = (la + fir) // 2

    if (la - fir == 0):
        single_sublist = lst[fir]
        return single_sublist
    
    if (la - fir == 1):
        first_list = lst[fir]
        last_list = lst[la]
        return check_lists(first_list, last_list)

    first_half_result = check_sublists(lst, fir, mid)
    second_half_result = check_sublists(lst, mid + 1, la)
    final_result = check_lists(first_half_result, second_half_result)
    
    return final_result


lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] ]

result = check_sublists(lst, 0, len(lst) - 1)

print(result)



So the function check_lists compares two lists using a for loop so it is O(k), in this case it will be used to compare the sublists with each other. The point is to check if all sublists are the same. The function check_sublists is the function that actually compares its sublists recursively. By using master theorem I get a=b=2. Also the largest sublist size is given by k. And nested list size is n. I am supposed to describe time complexity with these 2 variables. But using master theorem I am stuck because f(n) depends on k. I mean the non recursive part is k + constants. How am I supposed to do this?

Show check_lists, don't describe it.

"the largest sublist size is given by k. And nested list size is n.": what is a sublist here? Are you saying that the length of lst is at most k?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I am really sorry for that. I have edited it now.

@trincot So I have a nested list (lst) with the size of n. The maximum length of the any of the sublist is given by k. Example:
lst = [[a,b,c], [a,b,c,d], [a,b]] and its size is 3.
Any sublist should never be longer than k which is the maximum length. I am sorry if this was not clear.

The function will error out when the sublists are not equal, so the complexity is not defined. But your answer should be a function of both n and k. Why is this a problem? You determine the complexity of check_lists, and then the complexity of check_sublists in terms of check_lists.

@trincot Supposedly the last return statement gets two sublists from two calls to check_sublists, and then checks if they are equal by calling check_lists.

Yes, but the inner call can return None, and that is not supported as argument for the outer call. This code was not tested.

@trincot I wrote the code quickly after figuring out a way to solve the problem so I am probably gonna need to include an if statement in check_list. I was just focused on analysing the algorithms time complexity. So the problem I am having right not is that I don't know how to decide time complexity of check_sublist. I need to use Master Theorem right? I have that T(n)=2*T(n/2) + f(n) where f(n)=O(k). Meaning it is dependent on anther problem size and thus I don't really know how to think here. Can you maybe give me clue that will direct me a better way of thinking? Thanks for your time.

Can you first fix the code so it produces results without errors? Also include the main call, with an initialised list and the actual arguments. This should run without errors.

@trincot it is edited now, you get print None if all not equal or the list.

The worst case materialises when all elements of the top-level list are equal, as then the None condition in the check_lists is never true.
Reasoning
The base case of recursion hits when the sublist only has 1 or 2 elements. In the latter case check_lists compares two adjacent elements of the top-level list.
The recursive case also calls check_lists, with one element taken from the left partition, and one element taken from the right partition. It doesn't really matter which element from those partitions gets selected/returned: when we get an element back, it means they were all the same in that partition anyway, so we can imagine that it would have been the rightmost element from the left partition and the leftmost element from the right partition.
If we account for the elements in that way, we can see that all adjacent elements of the top-level list are subject to a call of check_lists, and exactly once. In a list of  elements there are −1 adjacent pairs, so we can conclude that exactly −1 calls of check_lists are made. As each call has a worst case time complexity of O(), the overall time complexity is O().
Formal approach
Before getting into the proof, I suggest to remove the handling of the base case where la - fir == 1 from the code, because the recursive case will deal with this correctly: the two recursive calls will in that case both hit the other base case (la - fir == 0) and so accomplish the same result.
So we then have this recursive function:
def check_sublists(lst, fir, la):
    if la == fir:
        return lst[fir]
    mid = (la + fir) // 2
    return check_lists(check_sublists(lst, fir, mid), check_sublists(lst, mid + 1, la))

In the case la and fir differ by 1, this program will still make one more recursive call than in your original code. But as the execution of such an extra call has O(1) complexity (as it hits the base case), this does not impact the overall time complexity. But it makes it easier to reason about the recursion tree.
The recursion tree (whose nodes are the distinct calls of check_sublists) is now a full binary tree:

It is binary because at most two recursive calls are made per call of the function
It is full because per execution of the function either two recursive calls are made, or none (never just one).

We thus have this recurrence relation, where () represents the time complexity for a list slice if size , i.e. where  is la - fir + 1:
      (1) = O(1)
      () = 2(/2) + O()
Using the substitution method, while assuming that  is a power of 2, we can expand with one step like this:
      = 2[2(/4) + O()] + O()
If we expand −1 times, we get:
      = 2(/2) + (20+21+22+...+2−1)O()
If we expand until we reach (1), i.e. when =log2, we get:
      = 2log2(1) + (20+21+22+23+...+2log2−1)O()
Now 2log2 is just , and the sum of powers of 2 is twice the last term minus 1, so we get:
      = O(1) + (2(−1)−1)O()
      = O() + O()O()
      = O()

Thanks for your answer. But I am a little confused. You said: "In a list of  elements there are −1 adjacent pairs, so we can conclude that exactly −1 calls of check_lists". I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but you are saying that if the list size is for example 12 then we will call the check_lists function 11 times? I double checked with pen and paper and I get  a total call of 7 which is not n-1. Did I misunderstood you or am I missing something? Also is it somehow use Master Theorem?

That is what I mean. For 12 elements, the function check_lists is called 11 times. See your code with an extra counter here. No this is not using the Master Theorem. Just the realisation that the number of calls of check_lists is −1 with the reasoning I have given.

What I meant to say was that there is a way to solve it using Master Theorem or is it simply not suited for it because I have sort of wasted a lot time trying to find a way? If I understood it correctly check_lists is called n-1 times and then the check_list operates k times in the worst case scenario so n*k but I have to ask, isn't there a little more to say about check_lists? BTW thanks again.

Can you clarify what "little more" about check_lists are you looking for?

Honestly I don't know, the constant operations are useless, Ig since we analyze the recursive function with Master Theorem in a divide and conquer algorithm it just felt weird. I do understand the reasoning and it does feel correct. Btw what about the Master Theorem question?

The Master Theorem does not apply, as it assumes one variable  that determines the input size, but you have two such variables:  and . But you can apply the Theorem if you take  to be a constant. Then it is the first case described in the Wikipedia article, and you get O(). As this is the case that is "leaf heavy", you can take this result and incorporate the worst-case leaf-cost into it and get O().

sorry to bother you again but while going thru our discussion I am still not sure I understand how to prove this formally?

I added a section to my answer where I use a recurrence relation and the substitution method to provide a more formal proof.

Yes I now realize what I have been doing wrong, why did you multiply the T(n) by 2? I get the aT(n/b) + f(n) part but why a=2?

Because the recursion tree is binary. Two recursive calls are made.
